# Angular config use same serve as backend API-Platform on docker-compose

Tags: angular, docker, docker-compose, api-platform.com, caddy

I normally use API-Platform with React-Next.js front-end with a docker-compose recipe from [API-Platform distribution](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/).

That setup uses only one serve - Caddy - to serve both front and back-end and it works great.

For a new project I am attempting to replicate the same setup but with an Angular front-end, but I seem to be missing the particular Angular serve config to make it work.

Running `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up` both work, but when attempting to open `http://localhost` I get the following error on Docker logs:

> caddy_1     | {"level":"error","ts":1655627402.8252528,"logger":"http.log.error","msg":"dial tcp 172.19.0.4:4200: connect: connection refused","request":{"remote_ip":"172.19.0.1","remote_port":"64320","proto":"HTTP/2.0","method":"GET","host":"localhost","uri":"/","headers":{"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0"],"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"],"Accept-Language":["fr-FR,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip, deflate, br"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"Sec-Fetch-Dest":["document"],"Sec-Fetch-Site":["none"],"Te":["trailers"],"Cookie":[],"Sec-Fetch-Mode":["navigate"],"Sec-Fetch-User":["?1"]},"tls":{"resumed":false,"version":772,"cipher_suite":4865,"proto":"h2","server_name":"localhost"}},"duration":0.001917417,"status":502,"err_id":"gz2ubcw01","err_trace":"reverseproxy.statusError (reverseproxy.go:1196)"}

The full code as is, is available at [this repository](https://github.com/BernardA/api-platform-ng).

In Next.js the following code is added to `next.config.js`:

```
 module.exports = {
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
       NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT || "https://localhost",
    },
  };
```

So, I seem to be missing the equivalent Angular server config to have it work and I am not at all proficient in Angular.

On `docker-compose.yml`, the env variable `NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT` is defined as follows:

```
pwa:
 build:
  context: ./pwa
  target: api_platform_pwa_prod
 environment:
  API_PLATFORM_CLIENT_GENERATOR_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy
  NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT: http://caddy
```

The `Dockerfile` at `./pwa` is as follows:

```
ARG NODE_VERSION=16

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS api_platform_pwa_common

EXPOSE 4200

WORKDIR /usr/src/pwa

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli @angular-devkit/build-angular && npm install

COPY . ./

VOLUME /usr/src/pwa/node_modules

FROM api_platform_pwa_common AS api_platform_pwa_dev

ENV API_PLATFORM_CLIENT_GENERATOR_OUTPUT .

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]

FROM api_platform_pwa_common AS api_platform_pwa_prod

ENV NODE_ENV production
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_ENTRYPOINT

RUN set -eux; \
  npm run build

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your ng serve
`--host 0.0.0.0`